# iTunes Connect - "we were unable to locate ads in your app"?

Tags: admob, app-store-connect, iad, interstitial

So this is the third time I've tried to upload the same binary to iTunes Connect, the only major difference (I tweaked a couple of small things) being that I've added the iAd Framework AND the GoogleAdMobs framework.

It's all working perfectly both on my simulator and on my Phone. The ads show up exactly at the point I want them to show up. First, Apple rejected my update because they couldn't locate the ads. So I sent them a video, pictures and a thorough description of how to find the ads. 
They just rejected it now because apparently

```
"PLA 3.3.12

We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. "
```

Even though I'm pretty certain Google AdMobs does use the AdIdentifier, no?

This is how I do it: in my viewDidLoad, I put this:

```
    if(modeHorsLigne == NO){
    _requestingAd = NO;
    [self showFullScreenAd];
    admobInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    admobInterstitial.adUnitID = @"MY ID";
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
    [admobInterstitial loadRequest:request];
}
```

Then, I have this:

```
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
if (_requestingAd == NO) {
    _interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
    _interstitial.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"Ad Request");
    _requestingAd = YES;
}
```

}

```
-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad didFailWithERROR");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    if ([admobInterstitial isReady]) {
        [admobInterstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }
}
```

The point being that if the iAD call fails, it loads the AdMob interstitial.

Am I doing something wrong? It's all working perfectly on my Phone and on the simulator yet the app keeps on getting rejected..

Thanks a lot